# combined colour bar that works both as colour bar and legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia

I recently came across a powerpoint slide containing a nice plot which I suspect is made rather with Julia or Python. The person giving the talk didn't give details on how to plot this (maybe he thought I was trying to get his data rather than the actual plot style).

Does anyone know how to produce this type of side colour bar?   As you can see from the image attached the colour bar works both as colour bar and legend for the different curves plotted.[image]

Comment: Presumably they created a half-transparent colorbar and plotted some thick lines in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to create a similar colorbar:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

def burr_pdf(x, c, k):
    return c * k * (x ** (c - 1)) / (1 + x ** c) ** (k + 1)

xs = np.linspace(0.0001, 3, 300)

c_k_params = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (0.5, 2)]
curve_labels = [f'c={c}; k={k}' for c, k in c_k_params]
curve_colors = np.linspace(0.98, 0.02, len(c_k_params))

cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet')
special_map_list = [tuple((c+2)/3 for c in cmap(i/256)) for i in range(256)]  # "whiten" the colors
for c in curve_colors:
    special_map_list[int(c*256)] = cmap(c)
    special_map_list[int(c*256)-1] = cmap(c)
special_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', special_map_list)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
for (c, k), col in zip(c_k_params, curve_colors):
    ax.plot(xs, burr_pdf(xs, c, k), color=cmap(col))

ax.set_title('Burr – probability density function')
ax.set_ylim((0, 2))
ax.set_xlim((0, 3))
cbar = plt.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=None, cmap=special_map), ax=ax, ticks=curve_colors)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(curve_labels)
plt.show()
```

The curves are from Wikipedia's [Burr distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_distribution).
The plot:

[image]